# delete values in child table when you delete values in parrent table JPA

Tags: jpa, jpql, java-ee-7

Parrent table: Currency - have 2 fields representing the foreign keys in the child table:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "inputCurrency")
List<Rate> ratesIC;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "outputCurrency")
List<Rate> ratesOC;
```

Child table: Rate - has2 fields referencing the primary key in the parrent table:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "INPUT_CURRENCY")
private Currency inputCurrency;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "OUTPUT_CURRENCY")
private Currency outputCurrency;
```

**Question:** How to delete a currency and all the rates that contains that currency? I don't want to use 
`orphanRemoval = true` on ratesIC and ratesOC fields from Currency.

**What I have tried:**
I tried first to delete all the rates containing that currency:

```
@NamedQuery(
       name = "deleteRateByCurrencyName",
       query = "DELETE FROM Rate r "
       + "WHERE r.inputCurrency.currency = :cName "
       + "OR r.outputCurrency.currency = :cName")
```

then to delete the Currency having the name currency from parent table:

```
@NamedQuery(
       name = "deleteCurrencyByCurrencyName",
       query = "DELETE FROM Currency c "
       + "WHERE c.currency =:cName")
```

I did it by calling this function:

```
public void removeCurrencyByNameAndAllRatesContainingThatCurrency(String currency) throws CurrencyNotFoundException {
        try {
            em.createNamedQuery("deleteRateByCurrencyName")
                    .setParameter("cName", currency)
                    .executeUpdate();
            em.createNamedQuery("deleteCurrencyByCurrencyName")
                    .setParameter("cName", currency)
                    .executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new CurrencyNotFoundException("The currency " + currency + " doesn't exist!");
        }
    }
```

**What I get:**

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: DELETE on table 'CURRENCY' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'RATEOUTPUTCURRENCY' for key (3).  The statement has been rolled back.
Error Code: 20000
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what JPA provider you are using because the query that you gave that I tried gave me a different error. Under Wildfly 10 with Hibernate 5.0.7.Final I got the following to work:

```
em.createQuery("delete from Rate r where r in (select r from Rate r where r.inputCurrency.currency = :currency or r.outputCurrency.currency = :currency)")
    .setParameter("currency", "USD")
    .executeUpdate();
em.createQuery("delete from Currency where currency=:sCurrency")
    .setParameter("sCurrency", "USD")
    .executeUpdate();
```